# Upload multi target App on App Store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store

I have an [app](http://itunes.apple.com/app/setvolume/id474167005?mt=8) on the App Store. After the first version, I decided to create a free Lite version of the same app. 
I've followed the instructions all over the web to create a multi-target application and I managed to install both version on my iPod.

What is the correct procedure to upload both my apps in the app store? Should I create a new app, named "Myapp Lite", and upload the binary as a completely different apps or maybe is there a way to tell Apple that those two apps are fundamentally the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your lite version is a separate target, it's a separate product in iTunes and you have to do all the same steps as for the regular version.

The only alternative would be to make the lite version the only product and use in-app purchasing to upgrade to the full version.

Answer (score 1):

You will need two create to app, one 'Lite' and one normal one.

Answer (score 1):

yap you should create a new app, named "Myapp Lite", and upload the binary as a completely different apps. If you upload as same app it will be considered as newer version.